How to control the memory distribution of INSERT SECTIONS when using INSERT in Linker Script
I have two linker scripts one for generating specific SECTIONS INSERT in my main linker script like this
SECTIONS {
  .bss.extra : {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    __am_apps_bss_start = .;
    *(__am_apps.bss*)
    *(__am_apps.sbss*)
    *(__am_apps.scommon*)
    __am_apps_bss_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } 
}
INSERT BEFORE .bss;

Another major linker script specifies memory distribution
MEMORY {
  FLASH (rx): ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 16M
  SRAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x0f000000, LENGTH = 8K
  PSRAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 4M
}

.data :{
    _sdata = . ;
    *(.data*)
    *(.sdata*)
    _edata = . ;
  } >PSRAM AT>FLASH

I hope the section I inserted is on my psram, but it always appears on my sram. I have no control over its memory distribution.
I tried using the orphan section method or using a section with the same name in the linker script to specify the output section.
